"ask of" meaning "ask about"
I occasionally come across use of "ask of" where I would expect "ask about"

The participant discussed that some adolescents may not initiate a conversation about a personal issue because of the anxiety they experience. When asked of ways in which a provider can improve openness in these situations, it was suggested to start vague, by asking if the patient has anything they would like to discuss.                              (Caring for   the Vulnerable - Perspectives;  eds Chesney & Anderson)


This is an interesting contrast to the military expert who, when asked of the possibility of disaster answered, "virtually nil".                                           (A Survey of Chemical and Biological Warfare;
John Cookson & Judith Nottingham; via Google Books)

Two common usages of "to ask of" are

to ask a question of someone, meaning to put a question to someone and
to request or demand something from someone/something

(see Farlex Dictionary of Idioms / McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms ... and OALD, via ELU.SE, respectively), neither of which seems to fit in the context at hand.
Is this an established usage? Or is it considered dated? Is it influenced by other phrasal verbs with "of"?

It seems to be an uncommon variation, but as you and Google Books show, it's not unheard of; I'd avoid it but you don't really make clear why you're inquiring. Do you want to know what preposition usually follows "of", or do you want to know if it's absolutely, indisputably wrong, or something else? I think it would be hard to produce statistical analysis in view of other meanings of "ask of..." More common are other uses of "of" meaning about: "tales/stories of", "explanations of", "ideas of", etc.

#1 "when asked of ways" = when asked about (odd). #2 "when asked of" = the question was put to the military expert (your #1 definition).

Addressed at ELL.SE.

@Yosef Other nouns force the 'about' sense: '[Medscape](https://www.medscape.com › viewarticle): 'Nonetheless, the first question to ask of any research article is whether its topic is relevant to one's own field of work.' Here, personification also (research articles being non-sentient).

The text of this book has other oddities, suggesting that one or both of the authors may not be a native English speaker.


When asked of ways in which a provider can improve openness in these situations, it was suggested to start vague, by asking if the patient has anything they would like to discuss.

The meaning of “asked of” is between “asked to provide” and “asked to describe” with the possibility of both.
The “of” (+ ask, tell, speak, etc.) hovers on the continuum between about and from. Its exact point on that line is determined by context.
About implies matters concerning -> “Ask him of (about) his journey”
From implies that something be provided “All he asked of (from) me was that I remained quiet.”
